# Datatable Button Error: Uncaught Unknown button type: print

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables, asset-pipeline

I've got a very strange problem with the print button on a datatable I couldn't find a solution for.

The strange thing is that I've already used the print button in datatables on different pages.

At the moment I am working on a ruby on rails project, including datatables with the jquery-datatables-rails gem, version 3.3.0.

Additionally, I include the CSS and the JS file for the buttons by referencing the file path in the assets pipeline (`dataTables.buttons.min` and `buttons.datatables.min.css`).

All the files are loaded without any problem or error message. 
Initialising of the datatable works as well, but then I add the option below:

```
dom: 'Bfrtip'
buttons: [ 'print' ]
```

to the initializer, it causes to crash with the error message below:

> Uncaught Unknown button type: print dataTables.buttons.min.js?body=1:18

Unfortunately I could not find anyone that has the same problem in the internet.

I followed the instructions on https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/, adding the two files to my page.

Also, when I try to use the *excel* button instead of the *print* button, no error message appears, but still no button is showing up.

The `div.dt-buttons` stays empty.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to include this file :

```
//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.print.min.js
```

For other issues like Excel as well, related asset files may be missing in your case. Check the list of JS files included in this example for reference.

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

List is given in Javascript tab of the example.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you have to include the [print button extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/built-in) in your page.

From [the docs](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/built-in):

> These buttons are not part of the core library, but rather are individual files that can be included as you require. For example you may with to provide HTML5 file export buttons but not Flash export buttons. This simply ensures that only the code you require is delivered to the end user.

Comment: That is why included dataTables.buttons.min.js and the CSS file to my page.... Or how do I need to include that?

Comment: You included it correctly, as the error message you're seeing is coming from the correct class (see the class [here](https://github.com/DataTables/Buttons/blob/3c444b63fd05733d9c8e03ec0571c20d4af6d542/js/dataTables.buttons.js#L783)). You could try to put a breakpoint there at this line and see what's the content of the `_dtButtons` collection there.

Could you please post the whole code you use to initialize the class and also your requires?

Comment: Thank you for your hint, born4new. The error occurs when selection "print" in an object, that doesn't contain "print", fails. Structure of the object: 

   Object {collection: Object}
      collection : Object
      copy : (a,b)
      csv : (a,b)
      excel : (a,b)
      pageLength : (a)
      pdf : (a,b)
      __proto__ : Object

Now my obvious question is: Why is "print" missing here?